# How to make CSS Grid items take up remaining space?

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I have a card built with CSS Grid layout. There might be an image to the left, some text to the right top and maybe a button or a link at the right bottom.

In the code below, how can I make the green area take up as much space as possible and at the same time make the blue area take up as little space as possible?

The green should push the blue area down as far as possible.

https://jsfiddle.net/9nxpvs5m/

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two"
    "one three"
}

.one {
  background: red;
  grid-area: one;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.two {
  background: green;
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: three;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    Three
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question as-is, but might still be of value: I'd do it with flexbox and an additional container around `.two` and `.three`: https://jsfiddle.net/9nxpvs5m/2/

Comment: your actual question doesn't seem to match the title.  the title suggests trying to take up the remaining space, but the actual question talks about taking up as much or as little space as possible.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Adding `grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content;` to your `.grid` will get you exactly what you're after :).

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two"
    "one three"
}

.one {
  background: red;
  grid-area: one;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.two {
  background: green;
  grid-area: two;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: three;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="two">
    Two
  </div>
  <div class="three">
    Three
  </div>
</div>
```

**Jens edits:** For better browser support this can be used instead: `grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;`, at least in this exact case.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a single-column, four-row grid. Used `grid-template-rows: auto auto auto 1fr;` and it now expands the final row to fill the remainder of the page. This is my goal — thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

A grid is a series of intersecting rows and columns.

You want the two items in the second column to automatically adjust their row height based on their content height.

That's not how a grid works. Such changes to the row height in the second column would also affect the first column.

If you must use CSS Grid, then what I would do is give the container, let's say, 12 rows, then have items span rows as necessary.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 15px);
}

.one {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  background: red;
}

.two {
  grid-row: span 10;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.three {
  grid-row: span 2;
  background: aqua;
}

.grid > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you can try a flexbox solution.

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 200px;
}

.one {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 30%;
  background: red;
}

.two {
  flex: 1 0 1px;
  width: 70%;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.three {
  background: aqua;
}

.grid>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had considered the *min-content* approach, but that value has weak browser support. It didn't work in Safari and Firefox when I tested it.

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach might be grouping `two` and `three` together, and using `flexbox`:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-areas: "one two"
}

.one {
  background: red;
  grid-area: one;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.wrap {
  grid-area: two;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.two {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}

.three {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="one">
    One
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="two">
      Two
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      Three
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly my line of thought. Flexbox is really my go-to solution these days. However, it is a pitty *flex*box isn't actually *flex*ible enough to get this simple layout going without an additional container around `.two` and `.three` - or is there a way?

Comment: @domsson Not that I can think of :)

Comment: I think this is a workaround so I'll wait a while before accepting this as an answer. A grid only solution if exists will be accepted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

When using grid, and you have grid template area used, and by chance you gave a particular area a width, you are left with a space grid does automatically.
In this situation, let grid-template-columns be either min-content or max-content, so that it adjusts its position automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not the most elegant solution and probably not best practice, but you could always add more lines of

```
"one two"
```

before the part where you have

```
"one three"
```

so it ends up looking like

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two"
    "one two"
    "one two"
    "one three"
}
```

Again, pretty sure this is just a work around and there's better solutions out there... But this does work, to be fair.

Answer (score -5):

Just use `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` in the CSS class of the item you want to fill the grid. Join a `max-width` property and a `max-height` property if you don't want a grid item inside a grid container to grow more than some size.

Comment: Wait, why is this scored so negatively?!? This is actually a valid solution. Upvoted!

Comment: Maybe it's not considered a good practice? I don't know years have passed and I'm doing backend now so I leave this to the FrontEnd experts.