# CSS Grid: Make an element fill empty space

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid where some elements span multiple rows. I'm trying to get the lower elements to fit snugly against the element above them, but they keep sticking to the bottom of the grid.

Setting align-items to start or stretch doesn't help at all.

```
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b"
    "c b"
    "c d";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(140px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  align-items: start;
}
.a { grid-area: a; }
.b { grid-area: b; height: 5em; }
.c { grid-area: c; height: 10em; }
.d { grid-area: d; }



<ul>
  <li class="a">A</li>
  <li class="b">B</li>
  <li class="c">C</li>
  <li class="d">D</li>
</ul>
```

This makes A and C touch, but B and D do not touch (unless you fill up D with more text). I want to make B & D touch, leaving a gap to the bottom (or causing D to fill the entire space).

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/JasonTank/Ltkhn6so/14/

Comment: There is already a question on that. Try the below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799207/how-to-make-css-grid-items-take-up-remaining-space

Comment: Thanks for that @Thameem I went through several different ways to frame the question and couldn't find anything.

Comment: There's a really good but non-intuitive solution to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645467/typescript-can-i-make-a-type-that-only-accepts-the-names-of-html-tags do you want an answer to that question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove your `align-items: start;` on the `ul`, and add in another area so you have 4 rows, then it should work as you expect.

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background-color: #20262e;
}

ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b"
    "c b"
    "c d"
    "c d";
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.a { grid-area: a; }
.b { grid-area: b; }
.c { grid-area: c; height: 10em; }
.d { grid-area: d; }

li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}


button {
  background: #f0f;
  color: #000;
  border-color: #00f;
  margin: 0 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="a">A</li>
  <li class="b">B</li>
  <li class="c">C</li>
  <li class="d">D</li>
</ul>
```

I've updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmtaqecw/) for you.

Comment: Thank you, this was great. I wish I understood _why_ it worked, but between you and the other commenter, I have multiple solutions now.